# Jelastic: how to contribute to Certified App source code?

Tags: jelastic

while setting up a basic 1 x NGINX load-balancer in front of 2 backends, I ended up in what it is clear to me to be a bug: the cron of this Certified App cannot be edited:

[image]

As you can see, in this particular App the cron file is owned by `root:root` and doesn't have the extended attribute (the plus on the right of permissions) necessary for the file to be edited also by the logged in user (`nginx` in this case).

All other certified apps allow instead the main login user to have crontabs, even though I found the permissions of each file vary a lot.

I've stumbled on https://github.com/jelastic/jem/blob/master/etc/jelastic/export.conf and it seems the file to go for proposing a bugfix, but it's last update if Aug-2016, so I guess Jelastic had closed much of its source code.

How can we contribute to Certified App source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

indeed it is a bug as cron file of nginx user isn't editable in a balancer template, by design in has to be.

As for exports.conf - this file left for backwards comparability, but no more used.

The problem will be definitely fixed in latest templates, as for existing containers - we would like to apply a patch to fix them, if you provide us more details about hosting service provider you are using - we will help with that.

As for contribution to certified templates, all the images are publicly available on Docker Hub, you can create your own version of template based on existing one if you build a docker image and in your Dockerfile you specify 
"from jelastic/nginxbalancer" as a base, then you can do any modifications to the filesystem. Next step will be just to replace existing balancer with your custom one.

Anyway, let's start with fix of existing containers.

Many thanks for finding out the bug!

Comment: So, Dockerfiles behind https://hub.docker.com/u/jelastic images are not public ok.
It's by the way nice to create a custom container based from Jelastic ones: it should be pointed out in the documentation :+1:

Comment: There are no secrets inside Dockerfiles, the reason why they are not public is simple - the Dockefiles are templates (they designed to be processed by template processor and build over custom CI solution),  basically there is a huge tree of files so change in one place may result CI prepare 200-300 images (including tags that need to be patched). So opening sources to public will require a person to have same CI to make that builds properly in a same way we do, so technically its much easier to do adjustments having binary image as "from ...." than just rebuild everything from scratch :)